# Create A Dynamic Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have monthly data frame feed that looks like this:

In Jan I have df1 coming in:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B'],
               'ID':['a1','b1'],
              'Age':[15,16]})

dic1={'Name': ['A', 'B'], 'ID': ['a1', 'b1'], 'Age': [15, 16],'Count':[1,1]}
```

In Feb, I have a new data df2 coming in and I feed the data into a desired programmer and it updates dic1 to dic2:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['C','A'],
               'ID':['c1','a1'],
              'Age':[32,18]})

dic2={'Name': ['A', 'B','C'], 'ID': ['a1', 'b1','c1'], 'Age': [18, 16,32],'Count':[2,1,1]}
```

Similarly, in March, I have df3

```
df3=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['D','A'],
               'ID':['d1','a1'],
              'Age':[50,21]})

dic3={'Name': ['A', 'B','C','D'], 'ID': ['a1', 'b1','c1','d1'], 'Age': [21, 16,32,50],'Count':[3,1,1,1]}
```

Basically it loops over the df1,df2 and d3 and Count occurrence as well as to update attributes. For example, 'A' occurs three times, so its Count in final dictionary d3 is 3 and the latest Age is 21 in df3, the original 15 in df1 and 18 in d2 is override.

I can simply append all three data and then run:

```
data=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=0)

(data.groupby('Name', as_index=False)
       .agg(**{'Count': ('Name', 'size'),
               'ID': ('ID', 'first'),
               'Age': ('Age', 'last')})
       .to_dict('list'))
```

But what I really want to achieve is to update the dictionary in a monthly basis, update the existing dictionary when new data coming in and I do not refer to all previous datasets. For example, when df3 comes in, my input is only df3 and dic2 and I do not need to refer to df1 and df2.

Comment: If your concat code works, then why not just run it every month?

Comment: This is because I have a new data in every week/monthly, the size of my concate data can be increased over time. So I want to feed the new dataset into a programmer and output a dictionary. Next time, when new data come in, I simply feed new data and update the existing dictionary. In this way, I do not need to append all previous data every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate). I would also use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) rather than `concat`:

```
from itertools import accumulate

dfs = [df1, df2]

def combine(a, b):
    return (b.set_index(['Name', 'ID'])
             .combine_first(a.set_index(['Name', 'ID']))
             .reset_index()
            )

out = [x.to_dict('list') for x in accumulate(dfs, combine)]
```

As a one-liner:

```
out = [x.to_dict('list') for x in accumulate(dfs, lambda a, b: b.set_index(['Name', 'ID']).combine_first(a.set_index(['Name', 'ID'])).reset_index())]
```

Output:

```
[{'Name': ['A', 'B'], 'ID': ['a1', 'b1'], 'Age': [15, 16]},
 {'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'ID': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], 'Age': [18, 16, 32]}]
```

##### iterative process

```
def combine(a, b):
    return (b.set_index(['Name', 'ID'])
             .combine_first(a.set_index(['Name', 'ID']))
             .reset_index()
            )

current = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'ID'])

# first month
current = combine(current, df1)  # or current = df1 the first time
print(current)

# second month
current = combine(current, df2)
print(current)

# third month
current = combine(current, df3)
print(current)
```

Output:

```
# first month
  Name  ID  Age
0    A  a1   15
1    B  b1   16

# second month
  Name  ID  Age
0    A  a1   18
1    B  b1   16
2    C  c1   32

# third month
  Name  ID  Age
0    A  a1   21
1    B  b1   16
2    C  c1   32
3    D  d1   50
```

Comment: @Derek. It was exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Hi thanks for prompt response. I am sorry maybe I was that clear. What I really meant was I want to create a dictionary after first month (df2 is not available then). Then when d2 is available in second month, I update the existing dictionary. So when every month's data become available, I update the dictionary. I think what you have here is to look back over all data and create a one time dictionary by standing at end of second month. . Let me know if I make this clear. Thank you

Comment: I have a new data in every week/monthly, the size of my appended data can be increased over time. So I want to feed the new dataset into a programmer and output a dictionary. Next time, when new data come in, I simply feed new data and update the existing dictionary. In this way, I do not need to append all previous data every time.

Comment: @Derek yes and no, my function is using the last state to update the dictionary. Assuming DataFrames, if `a` is the last DataFrame, and `b` the new one, running `def combine(a, b)` will give you the new output, you can then use that as the new `a` for the next iteration.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that in third month, b is d3 and new a is essentially d1 + df2. However, there is a practical issue on my end. What I prefer is that eg, in the third month, I only feed d3 into the programmer, which can update the existing dictionary and I do not need to refer to any d1 and d2 as all relevant information is already captured by the existing dictionary. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: I think this is what the code is doing, but to make sure we're talking about the same thing, can you please provide one or two more dataframes to illustrate this?

Comment: As I thought, this works with my `combine` function, I provided an example. You can keep updating `current` at each iteration, you only need to keep the last iteration and have the new dataset.

Comment: Got it. Can you also add the 'Count' column? Noticed that I do have a 'Count' column that counts the occurance.